# MVVM pattern filter listview and update on new item

Tags: wpf, listview

I've been struggling with this problem for a couple of days, but somewhere I obviously on a wrong track. Situation is as follows: I have a window with 3 buttons (Add New Task, Show Inbox, Show Today) and a Listview. My TaskViewModel class is has a ObservableCollection of TaskModel, with pretty simple Filter functionality. My class looks as follows:

```
public class TaskViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TaskModel> TaskCollection { get; private set; }

    public TaskViewModel()
    {
        TaskDataAccess ac = new TaskDataAccess();
        this.TaskCollection = ac.GetAllTasks();
    }

    public ICommand AddTaskCommand
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(this.AddTask); }
    }

    public ICommand FilterInboxCommand
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(this.FilterInbox); }
    }

    public void AddTask()
    {
        this.TaskCollection.Add(new TaskModel(9, "I", "New Item for testing"));
        this.GetListCollectionView().Filter = this.IsInbox; ;
    }

    private void FilterInbox()
    {
        this.GetListCollectionView().Filter = this.IsInbox;
    }

   ....
}
```

The filter functionality works fine, but when I call the new window "Add new task" it does not update the listview (here: this.TaskCollection.Add(new TaskModel(9, "I", "New Item for testing"));

I'd appreciate if someone could give me a hint...

Comment: 1. How does the listview bind to the collection? 2. Does it work if you temporary disable the filter?

Comment: It binds directly the ViewModel-Class: ListView Name="LstTask" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TaskCollection}". In the Window-Constructor I say: this.DataContext = new TaskViewModel(); calling new Entry window with:  TaskAdd add = new TaskAdd();
            add.ShowDialog();

Comment: okay, could you please set a breakpoint at `AddTask()` to see if it's really executed?

Comment: Yes, it is executed. And when I debug into private bool IsInbox(object obj) I'm able to see the new added item but the view doesn't show that item :( Additional info: if I comment out the line: this.TaskCollection.Add(new TaskModel(9, "I", "New Item for testing"));
and click save the button in the AddTask-Window it does not refresh the Listview (but the procedure is executed)

Comment: Maybe you could try to call `OnPropertyChanged("TaskCollection")` inside `AddTask()`?

Comment: It does execute OnPropertChanged-Procedure but ListView still does not show the additional entry :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this...

create a private field (say _taskCollection) to backup your property TaskCollection.

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<TaskModel> _taskCollection;
```

Then remove the private setter from TaskCollection property. Also remove the constructor code that loads the collection.

Instead write your getter this way...

```
public ObservableCollection<TaskModel> TaskCollection {
get {
    if (this._taskCollection == null)
    {
        TaskDataAccess ac = new TaskDataAccess();
        this._taskCollection = ac.GetAllTasks();
    }

    return this._taskCollection;
}
```

}

Let me know if this way works ....

Comment: It throws a NullReferenceException in AddTask(). I think, because of the new Form (Add Task) _taskCollection is null. Therefore it executes ac.GetAllTasks() from the data base again (actually what I wanted to be omitted)

Comment: @Adam, did u try implementing a backup collection field but? May be the getter code might not be corect and u can reintroduce the constructir code to load the backup field. But does it work with a backup field?